# how to authenticate http requests with Google generated id-token in .net web api back-end?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, mobile, google-api

I have a mobile App in Android that successfully authenticated with Google api returning id-token and also profile information. Now I need to integrate it with my login and registration which I use .net web api as backend. I found google explaind article but not with c# and nuget library and microsoft docs is little difficult to follow. It will be better if i can integrate it with Identity that visual studio provides when creating new project with user authentication generated.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my confusion next day after little digging and trying>
Ok first there are two ways of authenticating with third party which i was mixing them and I got confused.

1. First one in which your application is web or mobile but with web view.
2. Second way (that I'am using) in which native android activity handle going to google api, so the resulted id-token I manually send it to my api and use this code in c# to verify, requires Google.Apis.Auth library from nuget

> `var Payload = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(idtoken);`

[See image of steps need to follow in the second way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVTZN.png)

For more info:

- https://youtu.be/zZt8SFivjps
- https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating
- https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth